# R Shiny dates only show in 5 year intervals

Tags: r, plot, shiny

Here are my dates to be used on a R plot

```
dates <- c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
           "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")
```

When I plot the chart, here is the code, the dates only display in 5 yearly intervals, not each year displaying.

```
  plot(x = dates, y=Comp_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], type = "l"
         , xlab = "", ylab = "", col="grey20", ylim = c(-2, overall_max_z), lwd=3)
    mtext("Financial Vulnerability Indicator", side=3, adj=0, line=1.2, cex=2, font=2)
    mtext("Z-Score", side=3, adj=0, line=0.1, cex=1, font=0.5)
    lines(dates, Bank_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="green2", lwd=3)
    lines(dates, Curr_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="purple", lwd=3)
    lines(dates, Sover_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="red", lwd=3)
    lines(dates, Sudden_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="orange", lwd=3)
    legend(
      "bottom", 
      lty=c(1,1,1,1), 
      col=c("grey20", "green2", "purple", "red", "orange"), 
      legend = c("Composite", "Banking", "Currency", "Sovereign", "Sudden Stop")
      ,ncol=5
    )
```

Edit: this is what I get when I run your code. It seems that the legends are now spread out.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add `las=2` to the plot function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base graphics, if you want fine control over the axes, you can use integers to plot the data and set the labels explicitly.

The following changes were made:

- faked up some data to experiment with
- created a new integer valued x-axis range (1:17)
- used the `axis` call to map the `dates` to those values
- as Ryan Morton suggested, used `las=2` to rotate the x-axis labels 90 degrees.
- set the line types in the legend to be 3 (like the `lines`) with the `lwd` parameter.

So this is the code:

```
dates <- c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
           "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")

# fake up some data
set.seed(123)
gendf <- function(){
  cname <- c("USA","Mexico","Canada")
  df <- data.frame(dum=1:18)
  for (i in 1:3){
    df[[cname[i]]] <- cumsum(rnorm(18,1,1))
  }
  df$dum <- NULL
  rownames(df) <- c("country",dates)
  ndf <- as.data.frame(t(df))
  ndf$country <- cname
  ndf
}
Comp_selected_DF <- gendf()
Bank_selected_DF <- gendf()
Curr_selected_DF <- gendf()
Sover_selected_DF <- gendf()
Sudden_selected_DF <- gendf()

overall_max_z <- max(Comp_selected_DF[,2:18])
idx_country <- 1


# Now plot it out
xvals <- 1:17   # our new xvalues (instead of dates)

plot(x = xvals, y=Comp_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], type = "l"
     , xlab = "", ylab = "", col="grey20", ylim = c(-2, overall_max_z), lwd=3,las=2)
mtext("Z-Score", side=3, adj=0, line=0.1, cex=1, font=0.5)
axis(1,at=xvals,label=dates, cex.axis=1, las=2)
mtext("Financial Vulnerability Indicator", side=3, adj=0, line=1.2, cex=2, font=2)
 lines(xvals, Bank_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="green2", lwd=3)
 lines(xvals, Curr_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="purple", lwd=3)
 lines(xvals, Sover_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="red", lwd=3)
 lines(xvals, Sudden_selected_DF[idx_country, 2:18], col="orange", lwd=3)
 legend(
   "bottom", 
   lty=c(1,1,1,1), 
   lwd=c(3,3,3,3), 
   col=c("grey20", "green2", "purple", "red", "orange"), 
   legend = c("Composite", "Banking", "Currency", "Sovereign", "Sudden Stop")
   ,ncol=5
 )
```

and this is how it then looks:

[image]

Comment: Just one other point, how did you manage to get the legend to be below the plot area of the chart? On my version the legend sits on the bottom axis, but inside the plot area

Comment: Does running the code I provided give you the same result that I posted? It would be strange if it did not.

Comment: I really don't know. Try and change my code (with the fake data) so that you get something similar. That will be the MWE. Then post that as a question - but call it "base plot" in the question title. There are people that are far better at base plot than me (I am more a `ggplot` person).

Comment: OK, thank you. Seems odd. When the application opens it looks like the picture above in my question, but when I change the dropdown in the application to re-populate the chart, it goes back to the legend displaying in the middle of the plot area. As you said you are more of a ggplot person, do you think this chart would look better as a ggplot? If so, how hard would it be to translate the code to use ggplot as opposed to base plot.

Comment: Not hard, but I don't have time to do it today. You could also ask that question - there are lots of people that would do that eagerly - provided you give them working data and something that already works.

Comment: ggplot has a lot more options and flexibiity - but it is also harder to use.